# Including .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 in prerequisites for VS 2005 Setup Project

Tags: setup-project, .net-3.5

I have a problem. The thing is that I am using Visual Studio 2005 and .Net Framework 3.5 sp1. I have created the app and I want to have the .Net Framework prerequisite installed before however I can only select 2.0 . This wont go well since some columns in some of my grids will be arranged differently along with other problems. Is there any add-ins or something I can use to included .Net Framework 3.5 sp1 in my prerequisite list?

Answer (score 1):

with Visual Studio 2005 you can only create 2.0 projects. Only since VS2008 you could choose a different framework (2.0, 3.0, 3.5 in that case). Since VS2010 you can choose to target 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 & 4.0.

Grz, Kris.

Comment: thanks for the info. Do you have any suggestions? Some way I can still put the installation in a sub folder and include it in the setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

By specifying a launch condition in your setup project:

[image]
<sub>(source: [ultidev.com](http://ultidev.com/products/httpvpn/_images/VSsetup/LaunchConditionsFrameworkVersion.png))</sub>

Comment: thanks for the info. Do you have any suggestions? Some way I can still put the installation in a sub folder and include it in the setup.exe